# Bind color of SolidColorBrush and change it using converter

Tags: wpf, mvvm

There is a border inside a itemtemplate of a list view like this:

```
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border  >
                        <Border.Background>

                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=IsTrue, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=ColorConventer}}" Opacity="0.2">

                            </SolidColorBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
</Border>
```

bool to color converter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    switch ((bool)value)
                    {
                        case true:
                            //return System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
                            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                        case false:
                            return  new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
            return value;
        }
```

The ColorConventer is called but color of SolidColorBrush is not changed.
can anyone help that what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind the `Color` property of a SolidColorBrush to another SolidColorBrush. Change your converter so that it returns a Color:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is bool)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Colors.Red : Colors.White;
    }

    return value;
}
```

With your original converter you could have written the Background Binding like this:

```
<Border Background="{Binding Path=IsTrue, Converter={StaticResource ColorConventer}}" />
```

But the SolidColorBrush returned from the converter would have to have its Opacity set, e.g. like this:

```
public object Convert(
    object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (!(value is bool))
    {
        return value;
    }

    return new SolidColorBrush
    {
        Color = (bool)value ? Colors.Red : Colors.White,
        Opacity = 0.2
    };
}
```

Comment: great, your solution  resolved my issue, thank you so much.